# validate power of 2 numbers in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, between

How could I validate numbers between 1 to 1000 which they are power of 2?

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
   'threshold' => 'required'|between:1,1000|power??
  ];
}
```

Comment: Please dont edit answer into the question. Use the Answer section instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use closures in your validation:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'threshold' => [
                'required',
                'between:1,1000',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    if ($value == 0 || ($value & ($value - 1)) != 0) {
                        $fail($attribute . ' is not power of 2!');
                    }
                },
            ]
        ];
    }
```

See laravel Documentation => [Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#using-closures)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am curious about `($value & ($value - 1)) != 0` that how it is working?!

Comment: If your consider numbers in binary mode (1 and 0), the numbers which is a power of 2 will be like this(2=>10 , 4=>100, 8=>1000, 16=>10000 ...) and  numbers before these numbers will be like(1=>01, 3=>011, 7=>0111, 15=>01111)... so if you do an AND bit-wise operation on this numbers (e.g. 100 & 011 (4 and 3)) the answer will be 0, so... like a said the condition will be true if only result of the given value and value-1 equals to 0;

Comment: if you mind send your answer here, please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54743262/customize-validation-functions-in-laravel

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new [Rule object](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules) for that.

For example:

```
class PowerOfTwo implements Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return ($value & ($value - 1)) == 0;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute must be a power of 2.';
    }
}
```

To use the above rule, you would do something like this:

```
$data = [
    'threshold' => 256  
];

$rules = [
    'threshold' => ['required', 'integer', 'between:1,1000', new PowerOfTwo]
];

$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
```

You also need to add the `integer` rule if you want to test that your digit is between 1 and 1000.

Here's an [example](https://implode.io/CWTa5K) you can play with.

Comment: Your condition will return true on `zero` which is worng!