# customize validation functions in Laravel

Tags: algorithm, validation, laravel-5

I am curious about `($value & ($value - 1)) != 0` that how it is working in below validation to know number is power of 2?!

```
function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    if ($value == 0 || ($value & ($value - 1)) != 0) {
                        $fail($attribute . ' is not power of 2!');
                    }
                }
```

If I would like get numbers between numbers of power 2 in addition to power 2 numbers, what shall I do? can I use and modify this command?
(e.g. numbers: 1,2,3,4,6,8,12,16,...)

Comment: I Can't get your point.... what do you mean by `get numbers between numbers of power 2 beyond power 2 numbers`?

Comment: I want numbers of power 2 and also numbers which are between power 2' numbers. for example: 1,2,3,4,6,8,...

Comment: still can't get your point... could you explain it in persian?

Comment: A) 2,4,8,16,32 + B) 3,6,8,12,24
تابعی ک گفتین اعدادی که توان 2 هستند رو مشخص میکنه.. حالا اگه علاوه بر اون، اعداد بین توان 2ها رو هم بخوام، راهی هست؟ یا باید تابع جدا بنویسم؟

Comment: Now i've got your point, i'll get your answer in a minute

Comment: Thanks god.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved the algorithm. I created a Rule Object for my algorithm:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class DoubleThreshold implements Rule
{
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $issue = floor(log($value, 2));
        $power1 = pow(2, $issue);
        $power2 = pow(2, $issue - 1);
        $power3 = $power1 + $power2;

        if ($value == 1 || $value == $power1 || $value == $power2 || $value == $power3)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute is not in consider numbers!';
    }
}
```

To use the above rule, I did something like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'threshold' => ['required', 'between:1,1000', new DoubleThreshold]
     ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2) And [PHP Bitwise Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'threshold' => [
            'required',
            'between:1,1000',
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                $err_message = "Given Value is not acceptable";
                $next_power_of_2 = $value-1;
                $next_power_of_2 |= $next_power_of_2 >> 1;
                $next_power_of_2 |= $next_power_of_2 >> 2;
                $next_power_of_2 |= $next_power_of_2 >> 4;
                $next_power_of_2 |= $next_power_of_2 >> 8;
                $next_power_of_2 |= $next_power_of_2 >> 16;
                //closest upper power 2 to given number
                $next_power_of_2++;
                //closes lower power 2 number to given value
                $previous_power_of_2 = $next_power_of_2 >> 1;

                if ($value == 0) $fail($err_message);//check number is zero

                else if (($value & ($value - 1)) == 0) {}//check number is power of 2

                else if (($next_power_of_2 + $previous_power_of_2) / 2 != $value) //check number is between two power of 2
                    $fail($err_message);
            },
        ]
    ];
}
```